# How to toggle a class when the user clicks away from the link?

Tags: jquery

I have created a working toggle that will add a class of 'in' to a sublist when the anchor tag link is clicked. However, I am trying to get it to remove this class (which will hide the sub nav) if the user clicks away on a wrapper or elsewhere on the page. My code is:

```js
 $('#filterExtendListToggle').on('click', function() {
   $('.filter-extended-list').toggleClass('in');
 });
 $('.filter-extended-list').blur(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('in');
 });
```

```css
ul {
    list-style:none;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}   

.wrapper {
 width:100%;
 height:100vh;
 border:3px solid red;
}

.filter-inner {
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
}


    .flt-mod-01 {
        overflow: visible;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
   display:flex;
    }
    .flt-mod-01 .filters-list li {
        margin-right:10px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
    }
    .flt-mod-01 .filters-list > li a,
    .flt-mod-01 .filters-list > li a:active,
    .flt-mod-01 .filters-list > li a:visited,
    .flt-mod-01 .filters-list > li a:focus,
    .flt-mod-01 .filters-list > li a:hover {
        display:inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
        color: inherit;
        padding:5px 15px;
        background:#e5e5e5;
        border-radius:20px;
    }

    .flt-mod-01 .filters-list li a.active {
        background:#222;
        color:#fff;
    }

    .flt-mod-01 .filter-extended a,
    .flt-mod-01 .filter-extended a:active,
    .flt-mod-01 .filter-extended a:visited,
    .flt-mod-01 .filter-extended a:focus,
    .flt-mod-01 .filter-extended a:hover {
        display:inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: none;
        color: inherit;
        position:relative;
        padding:5px 15px;
        cursor:pointer;
    background:#e5e5e5;
    }

    .flt-mod-01 .filter-extended .filter-extended-list {
        position:absolute;
        top:30px;
    left:0;
        display:none;
        opacity:0;
        transition:all .3s ease;
    }
    .flt-mod-01 .filter-extended .filter-extended-list.in {
        display:block;
        opacity:1;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">   
  <div class="flt-mod-01 filters">
    <div class="filter-inner flex">
       <div class="filter-secondary">
          <div class="filter-extended">
            <a title="" id="filterExtendListToggle">More +</a>
            <ul class="filter-extended-list">
               <li><a href="" title="">Category</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try the `blur` event. Note that we can't really help you effectively without seeing a working example, or even just some HTML, though

Comment: https://codepen.io/Al-76/pen/LYPrrRR?editors=1111

Comment: you can use `blur` or `focusout` events.

Comment: Please include the HTML on which this code acts in an [mre], **on this site** not only on an external site (see [ask]). You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do a lot of what CodePen or jsFiddle does.

Comment: Here ,`if ($(e.target).is(".wrapper")` you have missed a closing bracket `)` just add that it should work..i.e : `if ($(e.target).is(".wrapper"))`

Comment: Thank you @Swati for your help. It now work thanks to your guidance. Kind regards.